# what is the difference between [NSLocale preferredLanguages] and [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

What is the difference between `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]`?

1. I am confused with Apple Documentation description and can't understand clearly, Who can tell me their difference? because I get the same data from them.
2. which one should we use at differente cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`, use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]` if you are supporting Mac OS X 10.4 or earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Both are meant to return the same thing, the first one is just more convenient.

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html) says: for `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]`

> The returned array contains the languages associated with the AppleLanguages key in the user's preferred order.

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says: for `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`

> The user's language preference order as an array of NSString objects,

Comment: which one should we use at differente cases?

Comment: What if both of these return nil like in my case?