# iOS App localization according NSUserDefaults' setting

Tags: ios, localization, nsuserdefaults

I have read about localization of iOS applications and now I would like to change application language according

```
NSString *lang = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Lang"];
```

but NOT according to system international settings.

Is it possible?

**EDITED**

I have found the answer in these posts:

[How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

[Change language of the ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611849/change-language-of-the-ios-application)

Answer (score 0):

**M1: NSLocale**

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

**M2:**

```
NSString *language = [[NSUserDefaults standUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

You should remember one point that "Locale" is different from "Language".

Comment: Shall I link this answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313786/the-two-methods-of-getting-ios-current-language-what-is-the-difference) of yours and from there to [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872356/what-is-the-difference-between-nslocale-preferredlanguages-and-nsuserdefault) ..??