# how to recall awakefromnib

Tags: ios, localization, awakefromnib

I would like to fetch each control such as UIButton/UILabel/UITextField when the .xib is going to show.And I know I can do it in awakefromnib,but How can I make awakefromnib be called again AUTOMATICALLY.Thanks!

actually,I goal is to localize .xib without follow the IPad/Iphone setting language.
I use https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAutoNIBi18n for localize.
Hope someone could give me a suggestion.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to re invoke of awake from nib?

You can force change of the application language by setting @"AppleLanguages" in UserDefaults before your application classes will be initiated. For example you can override +(void)initialize method in your AppDelegate.

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"en", @"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It is not clear way [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872356/what-is-the-difference-between-nslocale-preferredlanguages-and-nsuserdefault), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497047/applelanguages-value-overrides-the-value-of-language-set-in-ios-settings-preferr), but it works.

Also you can use custom localization subsystem (with redefined "NSLocalizedString...").